# Double click not working in iPhone safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

i want make a sample where on my web view i kept a button . when i double click it will go another page.This is working in desktop safari web browser . but not work in iPhone mobile browser. i tried with this link also

[Check this](http://appcropolis.com/blog/howto/implementing-doubletap-on-iphones-and-ipads/)

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/UXRF8/][1]
```

but it is not working i am new to java script . if possible any sample code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write code in jQuery then there will be no browser issue :

```
$("#target").dblclick(function() {
  window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
});
```

Comment: use proper jQuery CDN library in <script> tag